# Why does ToString format a number with the incorrect decimal separator

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, formatting, tostring

In my locale settings->numbers/currency, the decimal symbol is set to a period. Yet when I use the following in a Razor view:

```
<td class="number-col">@Model.TendersReceived[i].Wq.ToString("N")</td>
```

It renders the number with a comma as a decimal separator. The issue isn't with a different machine for the web server, because I use my dev PC's IIS. Or does IIS follow some other local settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

@Model.TendersReceived[i].Wq.ToString("N2")

or

```
<td class="number-col">string.Format("{0:0.00}", @Model.TendersReceived[i].Wq)</td>
```

Comment: I like your solution, thanks, but your answer doesn't really address the root question.

Comment: `@Model.TendersReceived[i].Wq.ToString("N2", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` does the job nicely, thanks. Just plain `N2` uses the IIS web site locale to determine the default decimal separator is a comma.